# Getting list of wear apps on Phone

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to get a list of Android Wear apps on the phone. I can get a list of Apps on the phone but I don't know how to distinguish the apps which have companion wear apps and which don't. *Is there a way to get a list of wear apps installed on the phone?*

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get a list of wear apps installed on the phone?

Wearable apps are installed of the watch, not on the handheld and, *AFAIK* , the only way is to run the same snippet of code you run on the handheld to retrieve the applications installed on the watch. Then you could use a `WearableListenerService`, to get the result back in the handheld. But in the end you need a Wearable application of your own

Comment: I am doing this currently but it seems very unoptmized way of acheiving it